# How to login users using on WordPress rest API with oauth1.0a?

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, wp-api

I have a multisite on WordPress and I was able to create users on my site using the API. I want to login users in my ionic app using angular $http method and wp rest API.

I want to know if there's a way of logging users in using the rest API over oauth 1.0a.

Show me the solution if possible in angular using the $http method if not then a snippet of any http client like postman would also work.

Answer (score 0):

For login, you can use some plugins like [WordPress REST API – OAuth 1.0a Server](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api-oauth1/) or to implement your own REST API route to achieve this in the server. In your Angular app you can add [angular-oauth1-client](https://github.com/seanfisher/angular-oauth1-client) or [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) and follow the documentation.
I am trying some similar but in Apache Cordova.